# Docker run only works after build

Tags: node.js, bash, docker

I can build *and* run a container with

```
docker build -t hopperweb:v5-full -f Dockerfile . && 
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3000:8080 --rm -ti hopperweb:v5-full
```

However when I run the container I get this error: `standard_init_linux.go:211: exec user process caused "exec format error"`

```
docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3000:8080 --rm -ti hopperweb:v5-full
```

Why is it working when it's run after `&&`??

I can run the image with bash: `docker run -p 127.0.0.1:3000:8080 --rm -ti hopperweb:v5-full bash` without issue.

This is my DockerFile

```
FROM ubuntu:18.04

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --yes curl
RUN apt-get install --yes sudo  ## maybe not necessary, but helpful
RUN apt-get install --yes gnupg
RUN apt-get install --yes git   ## not necessary, but helpful
RUN apt-get install --yes vim   ## not necessary, but helpful

## INSTALL NPM
RUN curl -sS https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/pubkey.gpg | apt-key add -
RUN echo 'deb https://dl.yarnpkg.com/debian/ stable main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/yarn.list

RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --yes yarn
RUN apt-get install --yes npm

## COPY IN APP FILES
RUN mkdir /app
COPY hopperweb/ /app/hopperweb/

RUN chmod +x /app/hopperweb/start.sh
RUN /app/hopperweb/start.sh
```

The contents of `start.sh`:

```
#!/bin/bash

cd /app/hopperweb/
yarn start
```

Comment: FYI each "RUN" block creates a new image layer. You want to group those when possible.

Comment: Thanks @jordanm, sure enough, I misremembered the tips from https://docs.docker.com/develop/develop-images/dockerfile_best-practices/ I thought it said to break everything out for readability, but you're absolutely correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your first command, the `docker run` is never executed, as the last command (`start.sh`) is run during your build and it will never terminate. So you were still running `docker build`.

Change the following line

```
RUN /app/hopperweb/start.sh
```

to

```
CMD /app/hopperweb/start.sh
```

Do not confuse RUN with CMD. RUN actually runs a command and commits the result; CMD does not execute anything at build time, but specifies the intended command for the image.

See: https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/builder/#cmd

Comment: I did start with CMD, but I was having issues and switched to RUN. Thank you!